# Чем отличается __construct от init() в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Чем отличается `__construct` от `init()` в моделях Yii2?

Вот например:

```
$model = new Model()
```

Здесь вызовется `__construct` и `init()`? Если да, то какая разница между ними?

Answer (score 3):

qiang:

> One of the reasons for init() is about life cycles of an object (or a
>   component to be exact).
>
> With an init() method, it is possible to configure an object after it
>   is instantiated while before fully initialized. For example, an
>   application component could be configured using app config. If you
>   override its init() method, you will be sure that the configuration is
>   applied and you can safely to check if everything is ready. Similar
>   thing happens to a widget and other configurable components.
>
> Even if init() is called within constructor rather than by another
>   object, it has meaning. For example, in CApplication, there are
>   preInit() and init(). They set up the life cycles of an application
>   and may be overridden so that the customization only occurs at
>   expected life cycles.
>
> I agree with you that the method naming is very important. Here in
>   Yii, init() method means that an object is already fully configured
>   and some additional initialization work should be done in this method.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3884-init-or-contruct/

init позволяет расширить функциональность компонентов. Безопасно сконфигурировать компонент приложения, переопределив init, не опасаясь нарушить логику работы конструктора, а так же убедиться, что компонент готов к работе.